# Android mediaPlayer and a bluetooth car/headset phone call

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-audiomanager, headset

I have a webrtc based app that need to work as a default call app. 
There is two states on a call: Initiator(1), !Initiator(2). When Im at state 1, app must play sound from earpiece and on state 2 from phone loud speaker, that can be achieved via

```
audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(boolean value)
```

But it seems that this works only on MediaStream.MUSIC type only. Anyway it works like a charm on phone-phone system, troubles came, when we have bluetooth device, like a bluetooth headset, for example. setSpeakerPhone will ignore bluetooth device and play sound from phone earpiece/speaker. Ok, I can check is there any bluetooth devices connected to phone and just play sound w/o setSpeakerPhone, not a problem. I can still play sound via MUSIC stream. But, if device connected to car, this will not work. Car seems to work with only AudioManager.STREAM_RING. I just cant understand this at all. What is the best practices for simulating native call in android? I need to play sound via earpiece/speaker and play it in RING stream, but it not working at all, have anyone beat this mission before?

```
  mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(ctx, res);
    mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    if (isIniator) {
        playFromSpeakephone(false);
    } else {
        playFromSpeakephone(true);
    }
    mediaPlayer.start();
```

Comment: Did you figure out a solution to this issue?